# Запрос MySQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, php, mysql

**Цель** - создать базу с миллионом записей X и Y (это координаты, значения от 0 до 1000).

**До чего додумался**:

```
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
while ($y <= 1000) {
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO map (x,y) VALUES('$x','$y')");
    $y++;
    if ($y > 1000) {
        $x++;
        $y = 0;
    }
}
```

**Что не получилось?** Запись в БД ведется только до 29той записи.

**Вопрос.** Как сделать рабочим мое решение (если это возможно и адекватно)? Либо как это еще можно сделать?

*Заранее спасибо.*

Comment: а зачем вам вообще такая база?

Comment: лучше сделайте хранимку, в которой в качестве параметров задаете количество итераций и вуаля call !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему, база не выдерживает такого напора. Попробуйте каждые 20 записей юзать `sleep()`;

А в чём проблема создать это непосредственно через `phpmyadmin`? То есть сначала написать много-много запросов (циклически в `PHP` выводить `"INSERT INTO..."`), а потом массово исполнить в интерфейсе `phpmyadmin`.

Comment: вручную написать и массово исполнить 1000000 запросов ??? база то выдержит ))))
как и выдержит просто 1000000 запросов из цикла программы

Answer (score 1):

так код то у вас нерабочий - есть ограничение на рост только переменной $y, а где ограничения на рост переменной $x?

```
$x = 0;
$y = 0;
while ($y <= 1000 & $x<=1000) {
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO map (x,y) VALUES('".$x."','".$y."')");
    $y++;
    if ($y > 1000) {
        $x++;
        $y = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: ну да, бесконечный цикл.
Откуда взялось число 29 в вопросе - непонятно

Comment: Цикл не бесконечный. Как только Y будет не удовлетворять условию - всё прекратится ($y <= 1000 & $x<=1000)